# How to get Microsoft Calculator result to cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any solution to get the result of default calculator to Excel cell by VBA?
I've tried to open the calculator:

```
Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp Index:=0
```

[image: Microsoft Calculator]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to calculate and show a value you can use VBA, it has math functions and all you need for simple and some more complex calculations.

Comment: I could be wrong but this is what I feel. In the earlier version of calculators, you could get that value using `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` by following the child windows `CalcFrame->#32770->Static`. The Win 10 calculator doesn't expose these windows. If you use spy++ you will see that there are 4 windows inside `ApplicationFrameWindow`. Which are `ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow`, `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`, `ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow` and `ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow`. Contd..

Comment: Contd from above: The window which is relevant to us is `ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow` and this window doesnt expose any child windows and hence retrieving the value using APIs is not possible. But like I said I could be wrong. Sendkeys may help but they are not relaible.